# Rails Nested layouts not working, blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to use nested layouts in Rails like [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts), but it is not working. It's showing a blank page. When I inspect the page source code, It's empty. In the logs there is nothing wrong:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-19 16:36:30 -0300
Processing by ComingSoonController#index as HTML
  Rendering coming_soon/index.html.erb within layouts/coming
  Rendered coming_soon/index.html.erb within layouts/coming (5.1ms)
  Rendering layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendered layouts/application.html.erb (42.5ms)
```

Controller:

```
class ComingSoonController < ApplicationController
  layout 'coming'

  def index
  end
end
```

views/comming_soon/index.html.erb

```
<% content_for :simple_content do %>

  <div>

   content here

  </div>

<% end %>
```

views/layouts/coming.html.erb

```
<% content_for :content do %>
  teste
  <%= yield(:simple_content) or yield %>
<% end %>
<% render :file => 'layouts/application' %>
```

views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>some title</title>

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <%= javascript_tag do %>
      window.userSignedIn = <%= user_signed_in? %>;
    <% end %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'logo.ico' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

    <% if current_user %>
      <%= link_to "Sair", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Registrar", new_user_registration_path %>
      <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %>
    <% end %>

    <%= yield(:content) %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do you have any clue what's going on?

Thank you

===================================

UPDATE

Solution: I had to change <% render :file => 'layouts/application' %> by <%= render template: 'layouts/application' %>

Comment: I changed but the same problem

Comment: To test - put some content outside of the `content-for` blocks to make sure that template+layout is being rendered correctly... it should appear on the page.

Comment: You should also look at the most recent version of rendering nested layouts here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts If there's anything to change in your templates - try that and it might all Just Work...

Comment: apparently the problem has something to do with the file views/layouts/coming.html.erb, because if I change the controller to use the layout views/layouts/application.html.erb(layout 'application') and change the file views/comming_soon/index.html.erb to <% content_for :content do %> it works.

Comment: It worked now. I had to change <% render :file => 'layouts/application' %> by <%= render template: 'layouts/application' %>. I did it before but I was using <% render template:... instead of <%= render template:... It needs to be <%= instead of simply <%. Thanks guys.

Comment: Great you figured your mistake, I recently came across this feature (after 10yrs with rails...) and tbh it doesn't feel that good. Some googling turned up this really nice gem  https://github.com/westonganger/rails_nestable_layouts